# All keys with their depth of nested dictionary on Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Sample imput:

```
a = {
"key1": 1,
"key2": {
        "key3": 1,
        "key4": {
                "key5": 4
            }
        }
}
```

Sample output:

```
key1 1
key2 1
key3 2
key4 2
key5 3
```

How do I iterate through every element of this nested dictionary and print depth of each separate element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use recursion:

```
def print_depth(d, start=0):
    for key, value in d.items():
        print(key, start + 1)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print_depth(value, start=start+1)


a = {
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": {
        "key3": 1,
        "key4": {
            "key5": 4
        }
    }
}

print_depth(a)
```

**Output**

```
key1 1
key2 1
key3 2
key4 2
key5 3
```

Comment: I have the exact same answer, but you beat me to it. :)

Comment: This won't work if dict depth level > sys.getrecursionlimit()

Answer (score 5):

Use stack to avoid exceeding the recursion limit (see [sys.getrecursionlimit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit)):

```
def print_depth(d):
    stack = [(d, list(d.keys()))]
    while stack:
        cur, keys = stack.pop()
        while keys:
            k, keys = keys[0], keys[1:]
            print(k, len(stack) + 1)
            v = cur[k]
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                 stack.append((cur, keys))
                 stack.append((v, list(v.keys())))
                 break
```

Output

```
key1 1
key2 1
key3 2
key4 2
key5 3
```

Comment: This is much better than the recursive version, essentially doing a Level-Order Traversal of the tree formed by the recursive definition of dictionary